# Wordpress admin never finishes saving page on site with large page count

Tags: php, pages, database

I have a Wordpress install with a very large amount of pages (a few hundred thousand), and over time it has gotten to the point where editing a page takes an extremely long amount of time. It would take several minutes just to open the edit screen, but I found out that it was wp_pages used in generating the parent page selection dropdown that caused that, so I removed it via a hook in my theme's functions.php and so now the edit screen loads just fine.

Now the problem I have is that when updating/editing a page, it never seems to complete whatever it is doing. The page keeps on loading after hitting update, but it does successfully edit the page within a couple of seconds (I can verify that on the frontend), but in the admin it just keeps going until I just manually refresh the page. Any one know what wordpress function might be causing this sort of timeout on saving a page?

I have wordpress 3.5.1 and I've tried to disable any running plugins. Any ideas?

Just to add, eventually I get a 500 server error after letting it run for about 30 minutes. Here is the server's log:

```
[Sat Jan 26 13:11:12 2013] [warn] [client 76.189.45.243] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://www.server.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=18173&action=edit 
[Sat Jan 26 13:11:12 2013] [error] [client 76.189.45.243] Premature end of script headers: post.php, referer: http://www.server.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=18173&action=edit 
[Sat Jan 26 13:11:12 2013] [warn] [client 76.189.45.243] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://www.server.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=18173&action=edit 
[Sat Jan 26 13:11:12 2013] [error] [client 76.189.45.243] Premature end of script headers: admin-ajax.php, referer: http://www.server.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=18173&action=edit
```

Comment: Small suggestion, but what if you delete all revisions from database, repair and optimize it? Have you researched for related topics here? At the right sidebar, there is a list of `Related` Q&A's.

Comment: Tried that too  :(   Not a whole lot of revisions at the moment anyways since the posts are mostly generated through Wordpress' API right now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried optimizing and repairing the table in your MySQL database you are running Wordpress on?

Your can manually do this with phpmyadmin:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-to-optimize-a-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin

Or you can install a Wordpress plugin such as WP Database Optimizer and set a regular optimization schedule:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-database-optimizer/

Comment: Thanks for posting. I have tried out multiple optimization methods without any luck  :(

Comment: Hmmm. What kind of hosting are you using? A site with hundreds of thousands of pages definitely wouldn't play nice on a shared hosting account. Wordpress tends to be somewhat of a CPU hog.

Comment: I do have a dedicated VPS with 1GB of RAM, but I'm 99% sure even getting a better server won't fix the issue. It's apparent that certain Wordpress functions just aren't meant for a website with the amount of pages I have. The fact that removing the parent page dropdown from the edit screen with a hook allowed it to actually load in a couple of seconds as opposed to timing out after an hour of loading. That was caused from Wordpress' wp_pages function. Frontend pages all load in under 2 seconds, even ones running a lot of queries generating dynamic pages.

Comment: That makes sense. If you don't mind me asking why do you have 100s of 1000s of pages on one Wordpress install? Surely Wordpress MU would be a better organization of your web content. Wordpress MU runs wordpress.com which hosts millions of blogs.

Comment: Eh, unfortunately it's a bit of a monster that has evolved way too much over the past year. We would have gone a totally different route had we known it would end up where it is at now, and we won't have the funds to rebuild it for a while still.